# Grouping with C# and LINQ Programatically (OnSelecting Maybe?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, grouping

I've been searching around and was hoping for some ideas - I currently have a gridview that gets its source from a linq datasource that gets its data on the onselecting command. However I'm trying to implement grouping...

any psuedo code or pointers on how I should do this? off the top my head my code looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
```

.. column setting and a closing gridview tag then on to the linqdatasource...

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" onselecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting" >
```

on to the .cs page!

```
public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
var db = new MyDataContext())
var orders = from order in db.tbl_orders 
select new {(order.Id, order.customer, order.state);
e.Result = orders;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out where and how to implement group in all this. Most the examples I've seen either do the grouping on in the linqDataSource code (which gives me fun errors think it has to do with the onSelecting) or slyly suggest I buy X product. I'm trying to group orders by State - so end result would be something like:

```
California (3 orders)
ID Order
ID Order
ID Order
Montana (1 orders) 
ID Order
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not really grouping as much as you are using sorting and then using summarizing headers (technically the headers are "grouped" I guess).  There can be several approaches, but none of them are necessarily simple.  Some links to attempts to accomplish this: http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/06/gridview-very-simple-grouping.html or http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the example how you can do it

```
        public void Button_Click()
    {
        List<Order> ods = new List<Order>{new Order(){State="cali",ID=1},
                new Order(){State="cali",ID=2},
                new Order(){State="nali",ID=3},
                new Order(){State="pali",ID=4},
                new Order(){State="pali",ID=5},
        };
        List<Grouping> groups = new List<Grouping>();
        var orders = ods.GroupBy(g => g.State);
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            Grouping group = new Grouping() { State = order.Key, Orders = new List<Order>(), IDs = new List<int>() };
            order.ToList().ForEach(o => { group.Orders.Add(o); group.IDs.Add(o.ID); });
            groups.Add(group);
        }

    }
    public class Grouping
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public List<int> IDs { get; set; }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public string State
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

This do exactly what you want except the dataSource and classes are different but the logic is same . I hope this will help you to get the idea.